# Why does my button change padding in the iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, user-interface, scaling

I am trying to add a button to a view in my iOS app. In the Main.storyboard file the button appears as this:

[image]

However, whenever I start the simulator the button appears as:

[image]

If it helps, I have the button paired to a custom class that consists of:

```
import UIKit

class RoundedButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        layer.borderWidth = 1
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 5, bottom: 5, right: 5)
    }
}
```

But I do not believe this is the cause of the issue. I think the problem stems from my lack of understanding of how scaling works in xCode but I am unable to find any resources on how to fix this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you add constraints?

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add constraints to your button and check. It will be perfect if you add the necessary constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Constraints are used to tell devices where objects should be and their sizes, even with different devices, you can create a pattern. Remember you always have to configure X, Y, width and height so your elements are placed perfectly. Except for labels, which sometimes doesn't require width and height constraints.

For your button, adding constraints to align horizontally, vertically, width and height should work.

Answer (score 0):

Add necessary constraints for the button. you can add in storyboard or programmatically.

In storyboard, you can add constraints like this:
[image]

For programmatically:

```
      let horConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourButton!, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: view, attribute: .centerX,
                                         multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
  let verConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourButton!, attribute: .centerY, relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: view, attribute: .centerY,
                                         multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
  let widConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourButton!, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: view, attribute: .width,
                                         multiplier: 0.95, constant: 0.0)
  let heiConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourButton!, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal,
                                         toItem: view, attribute: .height,
                                         multiplier: 0.95, constant: 0.0)

  view.addConstraints([horConstraint, verConstraint, widConstraint, heiConstraint])
```